# Samba Share to Mac problems

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, mac

I am working on building a small Ubuntu server to run Plex on. I have Ubuntu Server installed and up and running. I have installed Plex and Samba. I've mounted by separate internal drive (where I want my media to be stored) and made it auto mount when the machine is started.

I have set up the share in smb.conf like so:

```
[Media Drive]
 comment = Media Drive
 path = /media/mediadrive
 browseable = yes
 read only = no
 guest ok = no
 valid users = <myunixusername>
 writeable = yes
 public = yes
 available = yes
```

I have restarted the samba process and run `testparm`. The problem comes when I try to connect to the share from my Mac. I choose `Go > Connect to Server` from within Finder. I enter `smb://192.168.0.22` and connect. It then asks if I want to connect as a "Guest" or a "Registered user". I choose "Registered user" and type my unixusername and password in. I get the following error:

```
There was a problem connecting to the server “192.168.0.22”.

Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have problems, contact your system administrator.
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this so I can add media to the share in order for Plex to be able to manage it?

Comment: Have you installed libpam-smbpass?

Comment: No, what is this and what does it do?

Comment: It allows for syncing passwords and is needed for samba share.

Comment: @ArupRoyChowdhury I'm assuming that having run the command in the answer below I won't need this but it looks useful and might consider this once I have fixed the issue itself.

Comment: http://www.tonido.com/communitywiki/doku.php?id=advanceduses:sambashare

Comment: But surely I don't NEED that plugin? Can we just try to fix the issue without it for now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35710/discussion-between-arup-roy-chowdhury-and-rctneil).

Comment: @ArupRoyChowdhury Are you there? I have posted in chat?

Comment: Can you post the complete smb.conf file to check on errors there?

Answer (score 0):

Does your user has a Samba Password?

```
sudo smbpasswd -a <myunixusername>
```

This can be the same pswd as the password for your user -- it has not to be. It makes it easier though.

Comment: Yes, I done this with my unixusername and I did use the same password to keeps things simple

Comment: Any thoughts on what to check next?

Comment: Can you connect using `smbclient`?
`smbclient -L <hostname, ip, or localhost>` ? Use this from the server's ssh terminal.

Comment: Is this to run on my Mac or the server? If the server then it states smbclient is not installed. and My mac doesn;t know what to do with that command.

Comment: It is basically the client to your samba server. I don't know/think if there is a command line tool for mac out there. But install it on your server and check if you connect on localhost. It shows details about the settings, workgroup etc.